# Is there any simple way to get only the opening tag of a select menu in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the need to get a string of attributes of a select menu.  If my code is this...

```
<select name="foo" class="blah" data-toggle="blah">
   <option value="1">bar</option>
</select>
```

How could I return something like this:

```
class="blah" data-toggle="blah"
```

Or if that's not possible, is there a way to get the contents of just the opening tag?  Basically to return the following:

```
<select name="foo" class="blah" data-toggle="blah">
```

That way, I can use the following to return a string of extra attributes:

```
$tag = $tag.replace('<select ', '');
$tag = $tag.replace('>', '');
```

Comment: Do you want ALL the attributes of your <select> element or just some of them?

Answer (score 1):

This `getOpeningTagAttributes` function will get you just the attributes. Alternatively, you can call the `getOpeningTag` function by itself to get the full opening tag.

```js
function getOpeningTag(selector) {
  var fullHTML = $('select[name=foo]')[0].outerHTML;
  var closingBracketIndex = fullHTML.indexOf('>');
  return fullHTML.substr(0, closingBracketIndex + 1);
}

function getOpeningTagAttributes(selector) {
  var openingTagHTML = getOpeningTag(selector);
  return openingTagHTML.replace(/<[^\s]*\s+/, '').replace('>', '');
}

alert(getOpeningTagAttributes('select[name=foo]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="foo" class="blah" data-toggle="blah">
   <option value="1">bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I was thinking about getting the DOM element for the select and then iterating over its properties but in my tests, it seems that properties such as "class" (className) simply doesn't show up.  Don't know why this might be ...